# Error when opening a .nc file with raster package

Tags: environment-variables, raster, r-raster

I'm new to raster package in R, I was trying to open a .nc file with the package raster and some error popped out. In case you want to try I was using [this dataset](https://data.marine.copernicus.eu/product/GLOBAL_MULTIYEAR_PHY_001_030/description) from copernicus of monthly sea salinity for the years 2018 and 2019 (the grid was Quebec St.Laurence stuary and Gaspesie coast).

I opened similar data files before but never got this error, and a search online did not clarify too much

Here is my script

```
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)

#Load the .nc files describing SSS.  
SSS = stack('SSS.nc')
```

and the output error

```
Warning message:
In .rasterObjectFromCDF(x, type = objecttype, band = band, ...) :
  "level" set to 1 (there are 17 levels)
```

thnx

I expected to create a a rasterstack object to work with

Answer (score 0):

There is no error, there is a warning. If you want another level you can select it.

Either way, the "raster" package is obsolete, and you should try this with terra.

You can probably do

```
library(terra)
x <- rast('SSS.nc')
```

"Probably" because you do not provide a file. You should at least include a hyperlink to the file you are using. It is hard to help you without your example being reproducible.